# Vaadin-tooltip sometimes does not show. What is wrong? How to show it programmatically?

Tags: javascript, gwt, vaadin

I use a big HTML-canvas to draw a lot of thinks (squares and so on). When the mouse is moved on the canvas to "special" squares a tooltip should be raised. Therefore I overrided in my connector method *hasTooltip()*, that it always returns true now. On client side I added a *MouseMoveListener* to my canvas and when the mousecursor moves to a position of a square, I set the *description* and *descriptionContentMode* in the connector state with the acutal tooltip string of the underlaying square and content mode. In parallel the *VTooltip#TooltipEventHandler* also gets a *MouseMoveEvent*, starts the show timer and so on. At the end, after start delay is over, I can see my tooltip. If the mouse leaves the square I set *description* and *descriptionContentMode* to *null* and the tooltip disappears. So far, so good.
But in some cases it does not work. The tooltip is not visible. During debugging (and debugging mousemove-events is really annoying) it looks like, that I get my mousemove-event, but the tooltipeventhandler does not, so it does not start its show timer and so on. So I tried to show the tooltip programmatically, but without success. First I thought to "re-fire" my mousemove-event, so the tooltipeventhandler can re-act:

```
final Canvas widget = myConnetor.getWidget();

// myConnetor.getConnection().getVTooltip().connectHandlersToWidget(
//                  widget );

DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(
                pEvent.getNativeEvent().getNativeEvent(),
                widget,
                widget.getElement() );
```

The tooltiphandler recieves the event but in methode *handleShowHide()* it ends up in third line:

```
// We can ignore move event if it's handled by move or over already
if (currentElement == element && handledByFocus) {
         return;
}
```

I also tried to access methode *showTooltip()* in *VTooltip* directly via native access, because it is private:

```
private native void showMyTooltip( final VTooltip pTooltip )
/*-{
    pTooltip.showTooltip();
}-*/;
```

But alyways I get an error of unknown methode *showTooltip()* when I start Vaadin application in debug-mode. I tried to find out what could be wrong with my native call, but I am not so firm coding Vaadin client side with pure JavaScript. When I look into DevTools in Chrome I see something like this:

```
function com_vaadin_client_VTooltip_$showTooltip__Lcom_vaadin_client_VTooltip_2V(this$static){
    ...
}
```

It looks for me that there is a methode *showTooltip()*. So what is wrong with my call?
Does anybody has some ideas what else I could do? In my first tries I could also try to fire an blur-event first because in *onBlur()* *handledByFocus* is set to *false* so the condition in line 3 will fail.
But I am most interested in how to find out, why the tooltipevent-handler sometimes does not get the mousemove-events and to fix this issues. All other possibilities are a little bit stupid and not really "safe" again newer Vaadin versions and so on. I use Vaadin framework 8.5.2 but also before I had these problems.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: First thing that I see, that your JSNI is not formed right, you need to have the full class path there, refer to this documentation, http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I corrected it to `pVTooltip.@com.vaadin.client.VTooltip::showTooltip()();`. Now I get no errors any more but it does not work. I tried to debug it, but everything looks fine so far. I can't fetch the point what is going wrong. <grrrr>